# input type search "input" event not return keyCode value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have one input type search text box, I want to `keyCode` value within `input` event. but input event can not return `keycode`.

**Is there any way to get `keyCode` value within `input` event?**

Please check this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qvxw8e7m/) or code snippet.

```js
$('#search').on('input', function(event) {
  var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
  console.log(keycode); // undefined got
  $('div.log').text(String(keycode));
  if (this.value == '') {
    alert('Please enter a search criteria!');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="search" id="search">
<div class="log">aa</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

> I want to keyCode value within input event. but input event can not return keycode.

As you have identified, what you want it not possible.

Input events can be triggered without keypresses so they don't get any key data in the event object.

Use keyup/press/down if you want to know what key was pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
  <input onkeypress="javascript:return false;" id="txtChar"  type="text" name="txtChar">
<span id="spnCode" name="spnCode"></span>

$("#txtChar").on('keydown',function(event){
    var textBox = $('#txtChar').val();
     var charCode = event.keyCode
$('#spnCode').html('KeyCode:  ' + charCode);

    return false;

 });
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/u08d53rw/1/)